# React Native - Can't find variable: render

Tags: react-native, redux

I try to implement for the first time Redux on my React-Native app.
I have the error **Can’t find variable: render**

On my index.js, I call a Provider in order to use Redux. So I add a render it and it triggers this error.

Here is my index.js file:

```
//index.js
import React from "react";
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './redux/Store/store'
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And if useful, App Component that is called:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth'
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import Listing from './Listing';
import Menu from './Menu';
import Login from './Login';
import TestRedux from './redux/Components/TestRedux';

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX"
});

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user:'',
      loggedAndVerifiedOrNot: false
    }

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        //this.setState({ user: user })
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.emailVerified!=null)
            {
              if (user.emailVerified == true)
              this.setState({loggedAndVerifiedOrNot: true})
            }
        }
    });
  }

  render(){
      if (this.state.loggedAndVerifiedOrNot) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');         
      } 
      else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      }
      return (null)
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: App,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
    },
    Listing: {
      screen: Listing,
    },
    TestRedux: {
      screen: TestRedux,
    },
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Do you know where this error comes from and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
render() {
    return ( ... somethingToRender ... )
}
```

and this

```
    render() {
       return (
         <Provider store={Store}>
           <App/>
         </Provider>,
       )
   }
```

needs to be inside of your App component and removed from index.js.

You don't need document.getElementById. App is essentially your root element

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tested `render(){
      if (this.state.loggedAndVerifiedOrNot) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');   
      }
      else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      }
      return (
         <Provider store={Store}>
           <App/>
         </Provider>,
         document.getElementById('root')
       )
  }` but it triggers the error **can't find variable: document**. Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: You don't need document.getElementById. App is essentially your root element